# Cakephp hasMany return empty associated table

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 2 simple tables "Customer" & "SalesChannels", but data returned only customer data, saleschannels are empty, but with the HasOne option everything works perfectly without any additional modifications.

Here is their structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `sales_channels` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `channel` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`customer`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and their table class:

```
class SalesChannelsTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->setPrimaryKey(['id', 'customer']);
        $this->setTable('sales_channels');
        $this->setEntityClass('App\Model\Entity\SalesChannels');

    $this->belongsTo('Customer')->setForeignKey('customer');
    }
}


class CustomerTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->setTable('customer');
        $this->setEntityClass('App\Model\Entity\Customer');
        $this->hasMany('SalesChannels',[
            'foreignKey'=>'customer',
            'bindingKey'=>'id',
            'propertyName'=>'channels'
        ]);
    }
}
```

And Php code :

```
$customer = TableRegistry::get('Customer');
$customerEntity = $customer->find()->contain([
    'SalesChannels'
]);
echo $customerEntity->sql();
foreach($customerEntity as $e){
    debug($e);
}
```

But result didnt contain saleschannels's content, here is what it printed :

```
SELECT Customer.Id AS `Customer__Id`, Customer.username AS `Customer__username` FROM customer Customer


object(App\Model\Entity\Customer) {

    'Id' => (int) 1,
    'username' => 'test customer 1',
    'channels' => [],
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Customer'

}

object(App\Model\Entity\Customer) {

    'Id' => (int) 2,
    'username' => 'test customer 2',
    'channels' => [],
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Customer'

}
```

but with the HasOne option everything works perfectly without any additional modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I have to keep table name in seTable and bindingKey in hasMany not same case in it's first letter, that mean if 'customer' is lowercase then 'id' must write as 'Id', or if 'Customer' then bindingKey must be 'id', that's very strange

So this will not work:

```
        $this->setTable('customer');
        $this->hasMany('SalesChannels',[
            'foreignKey'=>'customer',
            'bindingKey'=>'id',
            'propertyName'=>'channels'
        ]);
```

I must write :

```
        $this->setTable('customer');
        $this->hasMany('SalesChannels',[
            'foreignKey'=>'customer',
            'bindingKey'=>'Id',
            'propertyName'=>'channels'
        ]);
```

or

```
        $this->setTable('Customer');
        $this->hasMany('SalesChannels',[
            'foreignKey'=>'customer',
            'bindingKey'=>'id',
            'propertyName'=>'channels'
        ]);
```

Can someone tell me how did that happend? I never thought this will be case sensitive...
this make no sense

Comment: Using `Customer` and `id` shouldn't work. Using `customer` and `Id` should. Because those are the actual names of the things.